# MongoDB // nodemon crash when i POST in postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, postman, nodemon

When i run nodemon file.js it show this (cmd) :

```
(node:23816) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
(node:23816) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.

And then when i POST in Postman show this (cmd) : 
events.js:287
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

ReferenceError: response is not defined
    at D:\Desktop\swag-shop-api\server.js:21:7
    at D:\Desktop\swag-shop-api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4889:16
    at D:\Desktop\swag-shop-api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:24:16
    at D:\Desktop\swag-shop-api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4912:21
    at model.<anonymous> (D:\Desktop\swag-shop-api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:493:7)
    at D:\Desktop\swag-shop-api\node_modules\kareem\index.js:315:21
    at next (D:\Desktop\swag-shop-api\node_modules\kareem\index.js:209:27)
    at D:\Desktop\swag-shop-api\node_modules\kareem\index.js:182:9
    at D:\Desktop\swag-shop-api\node_modules\kareem\index.js:507:38
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
Emitted 'error' event on Function instance at:
    at D:\Desktop\swag-shop-api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4891:13
    at D:\Desktop\swag-shop-api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:24:16
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

but when i do db.products.find({}) it shows everything i POST form postman

Please can someone help me...

[server.js file:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeKpZ.png)

Comment: Can you show your events.js file as well? Seems that it is causing the error.

Comment: The two warnings above can be removed by slightly modifying your connect method:
```mongoose.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })```

Comment: Can you show the code from your `server.js`? It says `response` is not defined in that file.

Comment: Welcome to the Stackoverflow community, here is some tips for a better experience when asking. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: @VedantBang where to modify this  "mongoose.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })"  (I'm new to MongoDB)

Answer (score 0):

If you need some directions to list your documents in a collection in mongodb, just use this code as a starting point:

In line 13 you must change the code to:

```
app.post("/product", function(request, response) {
```

The name of the parameter must be `response`.

Comment: thank you man but now the nodemon app crash in cmd when i run 'nodemon server.js' :( btw  im new to Mongodb and stackoverflow ...

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1070:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1120:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Comment: I found the problem but know shows this: (node:18836) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
(node:18836) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
Swag Shop API running on port 3000...

Comment: Yes, that's already commented in original post. There is a comment with a solution.

Comment: where do i have to do that ? CMD // mongo and than > mongoose.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })  ?

Comment: In mongoose.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }), line 5. Where you do your database connection.

Comment: Line 5: var db = mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/swag-shop"); after this or in this.

Comment: nvm i got it, thank you so much is there any way i can review you?

Comment: We are a community of developers, we are here to help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Line 5: var db = mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/swag-shop", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

Line 16: app.post("/product", function (request, response) {

Credits to: @Danizavts and @VedantBang.